# What is the AIX command for deleting a user along with his home directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, aix

I am trying to delete users in AIX systems using the `rmuser` command.
Following by `rmuser user`, I want delete user home directory also in a single command using `rmuser`, similar to `userdel -r userid` I am using on Red Hat and Ubuntu Linux.

Is there a similar command for doing this in AIX version 7?

Comment: Based on the `rmuser` man pages I just looked at, it doesn't seem possible using that command alone.

Answer (score 1):

The man page for `userdel` on AIX 7 makes this clear.

[AIX 7 userdel man page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/userdel.htm)

```
-r  Removes the home directory of the user.
```

Comment: i have tried the same command -r but its not deleting home directory

Comment: OK, you probably need to expand your question to have more details, with example output etc.

Comment: @steve, as per AIX man there is no such switch: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds4/rmuser.htm

Comment: You are confusing userdel with rmuser.  2 different commands.  2 different syntaxes.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by steve the userdel with the -r option should do what you want. However you should review the man page for some possible "gotcha's" - [userdel AIX 7.2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/userdel.htm). Looking at the man page there is no mention of /etc/security/passwd being accessed - I would suggest using "pwdck  -y ALL" to re-sync the various text files.

Also keep in mind that if the home directory is not local - such as user homes being mounted from a NAS the removal may fail if the mount does not have "root" access (assuming you are using "root').

Personally I recommend NOT to delete users - deactivate them instead. My reasons are:

- if the user is the owner of files / directories other than in his home directory you will end up with files showing only the numeric UID. I hate to try to backtrack something only with UID information when working an issue (I doubt that I will remember who the user of the UID was a couple of months from now.
- and from a security standpoint the file ownership issue has the potential to be a big vulnerability. Once you remove a user the UID can easily be re-used for a new user being added - and gaining ownership of any item owned by that UID.

The above recommendations are based on my experience in a large scale environment - various flavours of *NIX over 30+ years , hundreds on *NIX servers with over 31K *NIX user entries (active & deactivated). So there is a lot of old legacy "baggage" around that no one has a clue about. Things owned by a numeric UID created last century are almost impossible to backtrack - so they end up hanging around.

My $0.02 CAD of advice.

Ross